# PHP Warning: imagettftext(): Could not read font

Tags: php

Eu tenho um sistema captcha um tanto antigo que começou a ter problemas.

Às vezes funciona, outras vezes a imagem não é gerada e esses erros ocorrem:

```
[13-Sep-2019 23:48:05 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Warning:  imagettftext(): Could not read font in /home/user/public_html/captchac_code.php on line 230
[13-Sep-2019 23:48:05 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Warning:  imagettfbbox(): Could not read font in /home/user/public_html/captchac_code.php on line 71
[13-Sep-2019 23:48:03 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Warning:  imagefilledrectangle() expects parameter 6 to be long, string given in /home/user/public_html/captchac_code.php on line 200
```

Abaixo, forneço o código dos arquivos:

Arquivo: **captchac_config.php**: https://pastebin.com/kck0FKY1

Arquivo: **captchac_lib.php**: https://pastebin.com/Hzd8R65R

Arquivo: **captchac_code.php**: https://pastebin.com/0wTgVkva

Alguma luz? rsrs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Da uma olhada no documento  **captchac_config.php**, linha 44. Tem informações dizendo que se *CFontUsed = 1* (o que é o caso), o modulo vai escolher de forma aleatória uma "fonte" na pasta definida em CFontURL.

Depois, tem *FontNo = 34* com indicação que isso da o numero de "fontes" de deve ter na pasta. Ao seja, se vc tem por exemplo só 10 "fontes" na pasta, quando de forma aleatória ele vai buscar a fonte numero 5, vai dar certo, mas como ele acha (conforme na valor de FontNo) que tem 34, ele pode buscar a fonte numero 30 e neste caso, não vai dar certo.

Ao seja, vc deve configurar **captchac_config.php** conforme no numero de fontes que vc tem.

```
// 3. Fonts settings   
// The font used, can be 1 if random chosed from a fonts directory or 0 if specified
$CFontUsed = 1;
$CFontURL = 'home/'.get_current_user().'/public_html/fonts/font5.ttf';

// The number of fonts in the font directory
$FontNo = 34;
```